# commands of mercurial(hg) from dos prompt, how do this?

Tags: mercurial

what are commands for incoming,pull,push commands using dos command promt from mercurial(hg), in details i want to know that how i do this....

Help me all ways.....

Thanks

Comment: Can we please put "DOS" to bed once and for all. You mean "from the command line".

Answer (score 5):

The [Definitive Guide](http://hgbook.red-bean.com/read/) will answer all your questions.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to the [Definitive Guide](http://hgbook.red-bean.com/read/) linked by Vincent, see also `hg help` and the [hg(1) manpage](http://www.selenic.com/mercurial/hg.1.html).

Answer (score 0):

This didn't exist at the time when this question was asked, but in the meantime Joel Spolsky wrote another good tutorial, [Hg Init](http://hginit.com).